# Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'int', 'int[]'

Tags: java

```
public static int maxIceCream(int[][] costs, int coins) {
    Arrays.sort(costs);
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < costs.length; ++i) {
        if (coins != costs[i]) {
            coins -= costs[i];
            found = true;
            break;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return costs.length;
}
```

compare to integer and integer array

Comment: Since `costs` is a 2 dimensional array of integers, `costs[i]` is a 1 dimensional array of integers.  You are trying to compare that (`costs[i]`) with an integer (`coins`).  That's not allowed.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: What is your objective?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error message because "costs" is a 2D matrix and "coins" is an integer.
So, you can't compare an integer(int) to array of integer(int[]).
Try looping two times over the "costs" to compare to all the values

```
    public static int maxIceCream(int[][] costs, int coins) {
    Arrays.sort(costs);
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < costs.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < costs[i].length; ++j) {
            if (coins != costs[i][j]) {
                coins -= costs[i][j];
                found = true;
                break;
            } else {
                return i;
            }
        }

    }
    return costs.length;
}
```

Comment: great idea, it looks like the best option